# Mysql no exist condition

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

T1 = `common_member`

```
+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| uid           | username      | etc            |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| 1             | hehe          |                |
| 2             | crazy         |                |
| 3             | sence         |                |
| 4             | jjjj          |                |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

T2 = `home_friend`

```
+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| uid           | fuid          | fusername      |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| 1             | 2             | crazy          |
| 1             | 3             | sence          |
| 2             | 1             | hehe           |
| 3             | 1             | hehe           |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

T3 = `game_table`

```
+--------------+----------------+
| uid          | etc            |
+--------------+----------------+
| 1            |                |
| 2            |                |
| 4            |                |
+-------------------------------+
```

I would like to query data like condition as below.

```
Select t1.username AS username, t1.uid AS uid FROM commom_member t1 WHERE home_friend t2 fuid = $_GET['uid'] when the t2.fuid does not exist in game_table t3.
```

Since I use third party software, it was not allowed do 2 `select` in 1 query for safety issue, so I search stackoverflow and google, I try the code below:

```
$queryFriendList = DB::query("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('common_member')." t1 LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('home_friend')." t2 ON (t2.fuid='$_G[uid]') LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('game_table')." t3 ON (t2.uid = t3.uid) WHERE t3.uid is NULL");
```

But the code cant work properly, it will show all list exist in `t3` twice.
Let's say `$_G[uid] = 1;`

The out put should be

```
+---------+---------------+
| uid     | username      |
+---------+---------------+
| 3       | sence         |
+-------------------------+
```

because uid 3 in T2 is uid 1's friend but does not exist in T3.

any good suggestion for this query?

Comment: look into how joins work.

Comment: Do you want MySQL query for it?

Comment: yes, after query will fetch the data where `t2.uid` does not exist in `t3`